# Python - Use bpy.data.libraries.write on only the active action

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, data-blocks

I am trying to create a small addon to export actions into new blend files for easy access later. That way I don't have to dig around my other blend files looking for specific animations. I have been able to make an addon to export all the actions in the scene, but am looking to only do so for the active action on the active object.

Here is the code if someone with more experience can help me out. Thanks

```
    scene = context.scene
    obj = bpy.context.object                                                 
    action = obj.animation_data.action                                       

    if action:
        print(action.name)                                                      #Grab current action name

    if obj:
        print(obj.name)

    print (scene.my_tool.path)
    filepath = scene.my_tool.path
    #data_blocks = {action for action in bpy.data.actions if object == obj.name}
    data_blocks = {action for action in bpy.data.actions if action.name}
    bpy.data.libraries.write(filepath, data_blocks, fake_user=True)
```

Comment: Trying to plug this in and i'm getting "TypeError: write() argument 2 must be set, not list".

Comment: Oh ok got me brackies wrong.., make it `set(action)` or `{action}`  Makes sense it's a set as wont have more than one of same element.  Since you know the action is action no need to look for it again... `{a for a in bpy.data.actions if a.name == action.name} == {action}`

Comment: Using {action} worked perfectly. Thank a lot!